# Evaluating $\sin(5-8i)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, self-learning, hyperbolic-functions

We know that 
$$\sin(a\pm b)=\cos(b)\sin(a)\pm \cos(a)\sin(b)$$

We also know that 
$$\sinh(x)=-i\,\sin(ix) \quad\text{and}\quad\cosh(x)=\cos(ix)$$

> Now, suppose I want to compute $\sin(5-8i)$.

Then, 
$$\sin(5-8i)=\cos(8i)\sin(5)-\sin(8i)\cos(5) \tag{1}$$

Now we substitute trigonometric definitions of hyperbolic functions in (1). Then, we get,

$$\begin{align}
\sin(5-8i)
&=\cosh(8)\sin(5)-\cos(5)(-i\,\sinh(8)) \\
&=\cosh(8)\sin(5)+i\,\cos(5)\sinh(8) 
\end{align}\tag{2}$$

My hp 50g calculator gives answer to $\sin{(5-8i)}$ in radian mode,
$$(-1429.2566486,-422.79248111)$$ 
But R.H.S. of $(2)$ is 
$$(-1429.2566486,422.79248111)$$

> Where am I wrong in this computation?

Any member knowing the correct answer to this question may reply with correct answer.

Comment: $\sinh(x) = -i \sin(ix)$, so (multiplying both sides by $i$)  we have $$i\sinh(x)=\sin(ix)$$ (not "$-i\sinh(x)$").

Comment: @Blue, Thanks, for finding out where i was wrong.

Comment: Sign errors are an ever-present danger, but they can be extra-sneaky when $i$ is involved. Stay vigilant! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with

$$\sin(a- b)=\cos(b)\sin(a)- \cos(a)\sin(b)\tag{1}$$
$$\sinh(x)=-i\,\sin(ix)\tag{2}$$
$$\cosh(x)=\cos(ix)\tag{3}$$

we see that $(2)$ can be rewritten as

$$i\sinh(x)=i\big(-i\,\sin(ix)\big)\implies i\sinh(x)=\sin(ix)\tag{4}$$

therefore

\begin{align}\sin(5-8i)&=\cos(8i)\sin(5)-\cos(5)\sin(8i)\qquad\text{from (1)}\\&=
\cosh(8)\sin(5)-\cos(5)\sin(8i)\qquad\text{from (3)}\\&=
\cosh(8)\sin(5)-i\cos(5)\sinh(8)\qquad\text{from (4)}
\end{align}

which matches the result provided by your calculator.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sin(5-8i)=\sin \left( 5 \right) \cosh \left( 8 \right) -i\cos \left( 5 \right) 
\sinh \left( 8 \right) 
$$

Comment: Graubner, But $\sin{(8*i)}=-i*\sinh{(8)}$. I just substituted it in $\sin{(a \pm b)}=\sin{(a)}*\cos{(b)} \pm \cos{(a)}*\sin{(b)}$

Comment: Yeah, my name is Sonnhard. You must use the formula $$\sin(\alpha-\beta)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$ \sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} $$